# Losing updated records in cache when changing page

Tags: acumatica

I'm extending the GL404000 screen, and I've got the following problem :

When I select a few records on the first page :

[image]

I'm able to easily retrieve them in the updated cache :

[image]

But when click on "Next Page" on the grid part, these records vanish from the updated cache. Yet when I click on "Previous Page" the status "Selected" is still there, so It has to be stored somewhere in the cache, but I can't figure out where.

My goal is to be able to retrieve every single selected record on this screen so I can process them all. Even if they are not displayed on the page anymore.

What did I miss ?

Regards

Comment: It should be a software bug. Report it.

Comment: It doesnt look like a software bug, the "selected" property must have been stored somewhere, since I can still see the ticked checkbox while browsing to previous page, I just dont know where it's stored and how to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to retrieve 'selected' items within a custom button on the extension you can achieve the proper results with the following code :

```
public class AccountByPeriodEnqExtension : PXGraphExtension<AccountByPeriodEnq>
{
    public PXAction<AccountByPeriodFilter> RetrieveSelected;

    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)] //Must be true for button press to post modifications to the server
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Retrieve Selected")]
    public virtual IEnumerable retrieveSelected(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        List<GLTranR> items = new List<GLTranR>();
        foreach (GLTranR item in Base.GLTranEnq.SearchAll<Asc<GLTranR.selected>>(new object[] { true }, new object[] { }))
        {
            items.Add(item);
        }

        return adapter.Get();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it with : List<GLTranR> transactions = new List<GLTranR>();
            foreach (GLTranR tran in GLTranEnq.Select())
            {
                if (tran.Selected == true)
                {
                    transactions.Add(tran);
                }
            } but your solution is more elegant, thanks a lot. What is the point of the "Asc<" ?

Comment: Also why using searchAll instead of search ?

Comment: Search will only retrieve the top data record matching the specified criteria, SearchAll will retrieve all of them.